# Swift, classes based on extended protocol don't conform to original protocol

Tags: swift, class, protocols

These protocols are giving me nightmares.

I am trying to implement a couple protocols and classes conforming to them, such that I can have default implementations, but customized implementations are available by extending the protocols/classes. So far, this is what I have:

```
protocol ProtA {
    var aProperty: String { get set }
    var anotherProperty:String { get set }

    func aFunc (anArgument: String) -> String
}

protocol ProtB: ProtA {
    var aThirdProperty: String { get set }
}

protocol ProtC {
    func doSomething(parameter: Int, with anotherParameter: ProtA)
}

class ClassA: ProtA {
    var aProperty: String = "Hello, I'm a String."
    var anotherProperty: String = "I'm not the same String."

    func aFunc (anArgument: String) -> String {
        return anArgument
    }
}

class ClassB: ProtB {

    var aProperty: String = "Hello, I'm a String."
    var anotherProperty: String = "I'm not the same String."
    var aThirdProperty: String = "I'm yet another String!"

    func aFunc (anArgument: String) -> String {
        return anArgument
    }
}



class ClassC: ProtC {

func doSomething(parameter: Int, with anotherParameter: ProtA) {
    print (anotherParameter.aProperty) // Works fine.

}

}
```

Then, if I do

```
class ClassC: ProtC {

    func doSomething(parameter: Int, with anotherParameter: ProtA) {
        print (anotherParameter.aProperty) // Works fine.

    }

}
```

But, if I do

```
class ClassD: ProtC {

    func doSomething(parameter: Int, with anotherParameter: ProtA) {

        print (anotherParameter.aThirdProperty) // Value of type 'ProtA' has no member 'aThirdProperty'

    }

}
```

and, if instead I do

```
class ClassE: ProtC {

    func doSomething(parameter: Int, with anotherParameter: ProtB) {

        print (anotherParameter.aThirdProperty) // Type 'ClassE' does not conform to protocol 'ProtC'

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well `ProtA` doesn't require `aThirdProperty` – `ProtB` does. You cannot conform to `ProtC` with the method `func doSomething(parameter: Int, with anotherParameter: ProtB)`, as `anotherParameter` should be of type `ProtA`, as the protocol requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. You should just make sure that the declarations are semantically consistent. 
You should either create ProtD declaring the method with a ProtB parameter OR unwrapping the gotten ParamA parameter to use it as ProtB.

```
func doSomething(parameter: Int, with anotherParameter: ProtB) {
     if let a = anotherParameter as? ProtA {
          print (a.aThirdProperty)
     }

}
```

Comment: This actually works! It's not very pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

## The problem

When inheriting from a type, you *cannot* narrow down the types of the parameters used in overridden functions. This is what you've done by changing the parameter from type `ProtA` (a more general type), to `ProtB` (a more specific type).

This is a consequence of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Simply put, a subclass must be able to do (*at minimum*) everything that the superclass can do.

`ProtC` establishes that all conforming types have a function `func doSomething(parameter: Int, with anotherParameter: ProtA)`, with type `(Int, ProtA) -> Void)`.

Your modified function in `ClassE` has type `(Int, ProtB) -> Void`. However, this function can no longer act as a substitute for the one it overrides.

Suppose that it was possible to do what you tried. Watch what would happen:

```
let instanceConformingToProtA: ProtA = ClassA()

let instanceConformingToProtC: ProtC = ClassE()

// This would have to be possible:
instanceConformingToProtC(parameter: 0, amotherParameter: instanceConformingToProtA)
```

But, `ClassE()` **can't** take `instanceConformingToProtA` as a valid argument to its second parameter, because it's a `ProtA`, **not** the required `ProtB`.

## The solution

The solution to this problem is entirely dependant on what you're trying to achieve. I would need further information before being able to proceed.

As a rule of thumb, when overriding inherited members:

- Parameter types must be the same, or more general.

  - E.g. you can't override a function with a parameter of type `Car`, and change the parameter type to `RaceCar`. Doing so breaks your classes ability to work with `RaceCar`s, which it must be able to do by the LSP.
  - E.g. you can override a function with a parameter of type `Car`, and change the parameter to `Vehicle`. Doing so preserves your classes' ability to work with `Vehicles.
- Return types must be the same, or more specific.

  - E.g. you can't override a function with a return type of `Car` with a function that returns `Vehicle`. Doing so would mean the returned value is "less powerful" than the super class guarantees it should be.
  - E.g. you can override a function with a return type of `Car` with a function that returns `RaceCar`. Doing so would mean the returned value is "more powerful", and it does at least as much as what the super class guarentees.

Comment: typo in:  "must be able to do (at minimum) everything that the subclass can do": should be "superclass".

Comment: @shallowThought Thanks. Fixed. In the future, feel free to suggest an edit :)

Comment: I did not want to alter your answer.

Comment: @shallowThought It's not an issue, I would get a notification of your edit, and I would have to approve of it before it was shown publicly

Comment: Good to know. Will do in the future.

Comment: So how come you can give a `CustomUIViewController` instead of a `UIViewController`?

Comment: @Honey Here we're talking about the type *required* by the function. What the *caller* actually gives is a completely different story. If a superclass has a method that requires a parameter of type `UIViewController `, the override function cannot narrow the function to require `CustomUIViewController`

Comment: I see. Correct me if I'm wrong: You mean while I obviously can do `func doSomething(5, with: instanceOfProtA)` I can also do `func doSomething(5, with: instanceOfProtB)` on an instance of ClassE. Having that said I can't enforce a func to **require** a more constrained type as shown in OP's code

Comment: @Honey Exactly. The caller is free to provide a more specific type, but the function's author **cannot** require the more specific type.

Comment: @Honey For example, a caller could give a `Car` where a `Vehicle` is expected. But the function cannot require a `Car`, because it breaks the class' ability to handle non-`Car` `Vehicle` objects, such as `Motorcycle`.

Comment: Funny thing was I about to write an answer to this question and then I got dain bramaged on the 2nd error. I think you forgot to address his first error. Also do all OOP compilers enforce the Liskov principle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133485/discussion-between-alexander-and-honey).

Comment: @Alexander What I'm trying to do, specifically, is trying to alter [jakeheis' SwiftCLI](https://github.com/jakeheis/SwiftCLI) such that it is possible to create customized Command Signature logic, instead of just a Custom Argument Parser. Originally I attempted it via subclassing only (as I didn't really want to modify his source) but when that didn't work, I thought changing his CommandSignature Class to a protocol might work, but I'm stuck now. Ideally I want to change the original module as little as possible.

Comment: Most likely it didn't work also because the original module wasn't designed to have that particular class modified; but I guess nothing really wrong, I just decided if I was to change the module I'd want to do it in the most flexible way possible.